# How do I create a simple formatted table in Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to create a table with a certain number of rows/columns and formatted. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This was remarkably frustrating because the "Format Panel" that displays the table options doesn't pop up unless it's been previously activated:

To access the "Format Panel": create a table, click on the table, then...

- Opt1: click the Grid icon (its directly under the draw.io icon) and select "Format Panel"
- Opt2: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

- under **Misc** select a table of your choice
- then after clicking to edit text you gain options on the right panel to insert more rows or columns

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

- Double click in empty space.
- Use the table icon (highlighted) to select the table size.

[image: Insert table icon in the draw.io format panel]